# $Env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG powershell variable evaluates to true on non-tags

Tags: powershell, appveyor

I have an `appveyor.yml` definition which contains the fragment

```
init:
- ps: $Env:LABEL = If ($Env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG) { "Tag" + $Env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG_NAME } else { "nontaglabel" }
```

When later trying to access `%LABEL%`, on non-tag commits it contains the plain string "Tag". I expected it to contain the string "nontaglabel".

On tag commits, it contains the expected string Tag with the tag name as a suffix.

How can I assign the environment variable "nontaglabel" to the environment variable on commits that aren't tags?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `$Env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG` has string value of "false" on non-tag commits. Thus `($Env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG)` is evaluated to `true` as string value is not null or empty. Please use `($Env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG -eq $true)` or `($Env:APPVEYOR_REPO_TAG -eq "true")` -- both will work.